# Way to create a Skewed Scaled Reflection in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I have to parse an XML document & create a HTML element for every instance element I find.**

I need to create a img where its reflection *AND ONLY its reflection not the image* has a skew & is scaled. This means that I just cannot go:

```
img.style.WebkitTransform = "scale(0.26) skew(-1deg)"; // this will make the image scale & skew also
```

**Can you suggest a way/technique that would be the most efficient & easiest way to create a scaled & skewed reflection of an img element?**

Which of these would be best(although if you have better ideas I'd love to hear them :)):
- Create another HTML img below the actual image then adjust its style to make it upside down, scaled & skewed.
- Use a server side language(C#) to create the reflection as a .png
- Use CSS3 techniques/ways I dont know about?
- Use HTML5 canvas to create both the image & the scaled skewed reflection? This is a web application SOLELY for the iPad so it doesn't matter about browser-HTML5 compatibility.

This is an example of the XML file I parse:

```
<instance type="ImageBox" width="439" height="292" top="153" left="460" tReflectionEnabled="true" tReflectionScale="0.26" tReflectionAlpha="0.18" tReflectionSkew="-1"/>
```

Comment: You'd either have to duplicate the image and make a fake reflection, or use serverside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="imgWrap" />');
    $(this).after($(this).clone().addClass("imgCopy"));
});
```

CSS:

`.imgCopy { -webkit-transform:scale(.26) skew(-1deg);` }

I tested this and it works in the iOS simulator with the iPad.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hHXyj/)